# Maven internal dependency issues (non-syntactical error)

Tags: pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-dependency

I am kind of new to maven. And I watched a couple youtube videos to start with a quick maven archetype in VS code. I am working with python and java which requires me to use common code editors. But as of now I am working on java seperately to merge the files later.

Basically none of my import `org.<dependency>` are getting imported although there doesnt seem to be any syntax error with my pom.xml configured without vulnerabilities.

When I tried building pom.xml it did give me a build success message followed by a few warnings

```
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 5 plugin(s)
[WARNING]
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
```

1. I managed to resolve all pom.xml and syntactical errors, but none of the packages got imported from pom.xml
   `error: package org.json does not exist`
   This is a sample of what I am getting. I did verify that my java projects > maven dependencies > json-<version>.jar had indeed downloaded org.json. Similarly for every other library I tried to import
2. I tried commands like `mvn clean package`, `mvn install` but didnt seem to work. I even installed maven wrapper and tried the same commands (using `mvnw`) but to no avail.
3. Then I tried `mvn install -Dmaven.plugin.validation=VERBOSE` command but the `plugin.validation=VERBOSE` was not recognized. So I tried adding groupId and configuartions to the plugins to no avail.

It does seem to work for my partner in his machine and even on my own machine in netbeans.
But since I should later integrate it with some python code and the time required to learn IDEs is preventing me from making a switch.

Also this is my complete error for `cd "c:\folder\loaction\" ; if ($?) { javac NLUConverter.java } ; if ($?) { java NLUConverter }`

```
NLUConverter.java:11: error: package org.json does not exist
import org.json.JSONObject;
               ^
NLUConverter.java:12: error: package org.yaml.snakeyaml does not exist
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions;
                         ^
NLUConverter.java:13: error: package org.yaml.snakeyaml does not exist
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
                         ^
NLUConverter.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
        Yaml yamlParser = new Yaml();
        ^
  symbol:   class Yaml
  location: class NLUConverter
NLUConverter.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
        Yaml yamlParser = new Yaml();
                              ^
  symbol:   class Yaml
  location: class NLUConverter
NLUConverter.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
        return new JSONObject(data).toString();
                   ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class NLUConverter
NLUConverter.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class NLUConverter
NLUConverter.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                                    ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class NLUConverter
NLUConverter.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        ^
  symbol:   class DumperOptions
  location: class NLUConverter
NLUConverter.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class DumperOptions
  location: class NLUConverter
NLUConverter.java:73: error: package DumperOptions does not exist
        options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
                                                 ^
NLUConverter.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
        ^
  symbol:   class Yaml
  location: class NLUConverter
NLUConverter.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
                        ^
  symbol:   class Yaml
  location: class NLUConverter
13 errors
```

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to post my pom.xml as stackoverflow considers it as spam